# add to Google calendar option cut some description content off

Tags: google-calendar-api

We have coded a PHP page building the content of a calendar event. It is a mix of static and dynamic content for different parts of the email including the Description. When I receive the email in Gmail, the Add Calendar is displayed in the email header. An .ICS file is also attached. If I click on Add to calendar, the content of the description is incomplete, the length of content is OK, the problem is not coming from that point. When I open the attached ICS file in Outlook or Hotmail, the content is ok. If I'm adding the event into Google calendar importing the ICS, the content is ok too. But this method is too complicated for my end users.
Any suggestion? Is someone has already met this issue?
Regards

Comment: May I ask you how you are building the calendar event? Maybe you could provide a code snippet, which would be helpful to understand my the description is incomplete.

Comment: Hi, here is the code

Comment: https://symvision.com/code.txt

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your issue might be to use the Google Calendar API so you can create calendar events and afterwards add them to the users' calendars.

You should follow the steps from the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) and here a couple of code snippets that create a calendar and then an event with Google Calendar API:

**Create a calendar**

```
$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary('your_calendar_summary');
$calendar->setTimeZone('your_time_zone');

$createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
```

**Create an event** (you can customize the parameters to your liking)

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'your_event_summary',
  'location' => 'your_event_location',
  'description' => 'your_event_description',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => 'your_start_date',
    'timeZone' => 'your_time_zone',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => 'your_date_time',
    'timeZone' => 'your_time_zone',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'atendee1@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'atendee2@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

If you want to integrate the Google Calendar service with Gmail you can check these links that might help you:

1. [Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup);
2. [Gmail API Reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference);

Furthermore, you can read more about the Calendar API here:

3. [Google Calendar PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php);
4. [Google Calendar Add Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events).